# My application is stopped when executed. Error in my manifest?

Tags: android

My application is stopped when executed. I'm starting to program for android, just put a background and buttons, but it seems that I have problems creating the manifest. Before this project had many problems creating a new eclipse I put an activity together with the library and I started appcontainer_v7 errenter code hereored. To use the SDK 19 I decided to do everything manually.

**CLASS:**

```
package com.progra.cubebreaker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button Jugar, Puntuaciones, Instrucciones;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Jugar.findViewById(R.id.btJugar);
    Puntuaciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
    Instrucciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);

    Jugar.setOnClickListener(this);
    Puntuaciones.setOnClickListener(this);
    Instrucciones.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btJugar:

        break;
    case R.id.btPuntuaciones:
        Toast text = Toast.makeText(this, "Pendiente...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        text.show();
        break;
    case R.id.btInstrucciones:
        Toast text1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Pendiente...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        text1.show();
        break;

    }

}   

}
```

**LAYOUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/fondo1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btInstrucciones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btPuntuaciones"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:text="@string/instrucciones"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="italic|normal|bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btPuntuaciones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btInstrucciones"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="@string/puntuaciones"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="italic|normal|bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btJugar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btPuntuaciones"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:text="@string/jugar"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="italic|normal|bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MANIFEST:**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.progra.cubebreaker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="9"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity 
           android:name=".Menu"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>

       </activity>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Please print the error

Comment: Is `Button` a custom class? I don't see how you can do `Jugar.findViewById(R.id.btJugar);` and manage to compile it successfully.

Comment: I think before asking this question you have to learn from android basic tutorial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

You are not mapping the layout objects to java class objects thats y ur application is crashing.
You need to map the java button by converting id of button or any other attribute to (Button) etc.
Modify your code :

```
Jugar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
Puntuaciones= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPuntuaciones);
Instrucciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I hope answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this code,

```
    Jugar.findViewById(R.id.btJugar);
    Puntuaciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
    Instrucciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
```

by

```
        Jugar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btJugar);
        Puntuaciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPuntuaciones);
        Instrucciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is crashing as you are not initializing the widgets in your code.
Here is the error:

```
Jugar.findViewById(R.id.btJugar);
Puntuaciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
Instrucciones.findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
```

Change it to:

```
 Jugar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btJugar);
 Puntuaciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPuntuaciones);
 Instrucciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btInstrucciones);
```